# jQuery highlight for table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 4 coloumn table named col1, col2, col3, col4. The columns are having different colors. The col1 has tool tip link. When cursor is pointed over the link, the tool tip displays and also the the background image for that row to be changed.  The entire table has one single background image.

I tried with the following code, but in Chrome and Safari it displays the same color for all 4 cols (color of first col ).

```
$(function() {
$('td:first-child a').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('table.benefitstable tbody tr').toggleClass("highlight");
});
});

.benefitstable tbody tr.highlight {
background:url(../images/tablerowhover.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

It is almost equivalent to do without jQuery with following tag:

```
.benefitstable tbody tr:hover {
background:url(../images/tablerowhover.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Twitter bootstrap zebra table implements this, might want to check it out http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#tables

Comment: Not interested in twitter bootstrap since it specifies 18px margin / padding for many elements.

Answer (score 0):

What don't you try: $(this).parent('table.benefitstable tbody tr').toggleClass("highlight");
Since any TD element will be a child of the row? I'm not sure about the use of closest() there...

Comment: My guess is because he/she's actually selecting `a`, not the `td`.

Comment: Hover need to work only when mouse over on link in the first column and not on other columns.

Comment: I've actually done things like this as well and it works: $(this).parent().parent(). It may not be the best practice, but Jquery parentsUntil('tr') function will go up to the TR that you want and select the TD, not the actual parent. What it needs is a parentsUntilandIncluding() or something like that, IMO. Sorry I missed the ('a') part...

Comment: I am making the following changes and it highlights only the hover cell only instead of whole row.                                                      $(function() {
    $('td').hover(function() {
        $(this).closest('table.benefitstable tbody tr td.col1').toggleClass("highlight1");
  $(this).closest('table.benefitstable tbody tr td.col2').toggleClass("highlight2");
  $(this).closest('table.benefitstable tbody tr td.col3').toggleClass("highlight2");
  $(this).closest('table.benefitstable tbody tr td.col4').toggleClass("highlight2");
    });
});